# Why is parasitic capacitance much more mentioned than parasitic inductance in MOSFET?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, parasitic-capacitance

It seems to me that in MOSFETs, parasitic inductance would be equally as important as parasitic capacitance. However, I have never seen anyone discussing parasitic inductance seriously.

Is parasitic inductance's influence on MOSFET operations not really important, or is of much smaller influence compared to parasitic capacitance?

Comment: It is much smaller and hence the influence is not really important.

Comment: In what context? IC design? baseband amplifiers? RF amplifiers? Power electronics?

Comment: in context of RF amplifier.

Comment: A high power MOSFET can be viewed as thousands of small signal MOSFETs in parallel on the same die. I believe that's how they used to be manufactured, whether that's still true I don't know.  Anyway, consider that tiny (pf) capacitances in parallel add, to give several nanofarads, while tiny inductances in parallel *reduce* the overall inductance, and you'll understand why - in the context of power MOSFETs - it's the capacitance that matters. For small signal amplification I'd expect both to matter. See photo on http://www.embedded.com/print/4019426

Answer (score 3):

For typical uses (very generally 10 - 100 V; 1-10 A, < 10 MHz), the physics of silicon mean that the capacitance of the FET structures (and parasitics associated with them) have values which have a more significant circuit effect than the inductance (generally associated with bonding wires and the package structure).

However, at high frequencies (certainly > 100 MHz); with certain DC/DC converters (low V, and high currents), the inductive parasitics can become significant and are critical. In these operating ranges, inductance in the gate lead can significantly affect the rate at which the transistor can be switched; inductance in the source can also affect this. inductance in the drain can cause large damaging voltages to appear between the internal transistor source and drain nodes, potentially damaging the device.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the MOSFET accounts for variety of capacitances which include junction capacitances,sidewall capacitances which come into picture at high frequencies to limit frequency response.

Talking about the inductances,to operate, the MOSFET must be connected to the external circuit, most of the time using wire bonding These connections exhibit a parasitic inductances.

These parasitic inductances  are neglected when we typically use the MOSFET as an amplifier because they operate in saturation where current is almost a constant.However, when a MOSFET is used for high frequency switching applications, they become equally important as the parasitic capacitances.

As an example,the gate inductance and the input capacitance of the transistor can constitute an oscillator. This must be avoided as it results in very high switching losses.

Answer (score 1):

The parasitic inductance is the sum of the bonding wire and the PCB traces .So its really a function of package type and board layout.Most of the time the parasitic capacitance is more significant .When you compare the energy stored in C to L you find that C is much higher     .This is why for powermos its generally more rewarding to implement ZVS rather than ZCS despite the fact that they are both valid         .At really high power and high currents and low voltages the parasitic inductance does get much more significant .Remember that the voltage across a inductive trace =  L times the rate of change of current .The parasitic inductance can and does resonate with the voltage variant mosfet capacitance causing parasitic oscillations generally at VHF .If these are not dealt with you can fail radiated EMC.The induced voltages due to rapidly changing currents can muck up your circuit or sensitive circuitry elsewhere in the product              .Over the decades the parasitic capacitance of powermos has got worse as on resistance has come down but inductance has got a little better with SMD.